# Prevent object created by reference to change when the original one is changed

Tags: javascript, reference, javascript-objects

Probably this thing was talked before but I haven't find a solution to solve my problem yet.

So, my issue is this:

I'm saving into a variable the value of an object.

`const aux = this.myObj;`

the Object (`this.myObj`) is changed by some operations after that but I want to save its initial value and be able to re-assing it to it.

Something like:

`this.myObj = aux`

but as expected, the aux is also modified when the original one is.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clone the object and save it's data to the other variable.

```
var clone = Object.assign({}, obj);
```

In case of nested object, Deep cloning can be achieved using various methods. One of that for a simple structured object with nested key-value pairs.

```
var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

or use library like underscore and lodash.

Comment: This is a good answer, but what I would also add is that it's not a deep clone,.  eg.  `aux.x.y = 2` would still change `x.y` in `myObj`

Comment: Yes. That depends on use case again. Have edited my answer to incorporate that.  @Keith :)

Answer (score 1):

`Object.assign({}, obj)` simply copies property values of the given object so it wouldn't a good fix, I would recommend [lodash's _.cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep) as it does deep cloning for you.
You would just have just to do the following.

`const aux = _.cloneDeep(this.myObj)`